# adding an modal window on jsp page onload

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am new to the jsp. I am creating a jsp page.**Index.jsp**, I want that when this index.jsp is loading one modal pop up should appear that would ask the user to enter some information.Please let me know how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using jQuery.Download jQuery file and place it under your webapps  directory,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(showWindow());
        function showWindow(){
            window.open('mathutil.jsp','myWindow','height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,continued from previous linemenubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');
        }   
    </script>
```

This will be called before your JSP page get loaded.

If you want something as soon as page get loaded (e.g. wait until all assets have finished downloading, such as images and scripts.) use `onload()` in your `body` tag.

Comment: But i want it should open as a modal